# How to call Struts 2 client-side validation using theme="simple"?

Tags: validation, jakarta-ee, struts2, themes, client-side

When applying **`theme="simple"`** to my Struts 2 form tag, the JavaScript `validateForm_<formName>` function isn't "generated" anymore.

#### With the simple theme

The form tag :

```
<s:form id="editForm" validate="true" action="Edit" namespace="/ValidationTest" theme="simple">
```

From JavaScript console :

```
> validateForm_editForm()
ReferenceError: validateForm_editForm is not defined
```

#### Without the simple theme

It works fine without the theme (so I assume that XML validation files and other configuration are correct) :

```
<s:form id="editForm" validate="true" action="Edit" namespace="/ValidationTest">
```

JS console :

```
> validateForm_editForm()
false
```

---

I don't know if it's important but the `<s:head />` tag is present :

```
<head>
    ...
    <s:head />
</head>
```

---

- **Is there something specific to include in order for Struts to generate the `validateForm_<formName>` function (similar to adding `<s:fielderror />` tags with the simple theme) ?**
- I cannot find any "official" documentation and reference to this autogenerated JS function, mainly because its name is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try to add two javascript-s to JSP.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/struts/xhtml/validation.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/struts/utils.js"/>"></script>
```

Change your form to something like this:

```
<s:form id="editForm" onreset="clearErrorMessages(this);clearErrorLabels(this);"
    onsubmit="return validateForm_editForm();" theme="simple" ...>
```

Additionally you need to copy content from `form-close-validate.ftl` from `xhtml` theme to `form-close.ftl` in `simple` theme.

As you can see there is a lot of workarounds to get this working. IMO if you want to use javascript validation and `simple` look of form elements then use `xhtml` theme in `<s:form>` tag and set `simple` theme in form elements.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. The JS files are included and provide functions like `clearErrorMessages` and others, but no `validateXXX` of any kind.

Comment: Yep, `validateForm*` method is in the `xhtml` theme `form-close-validate.ftl`. See an update.